# Python dot-syntax-functions based on condition

Tags: python

Is it possible in python to call dot-syntax-function based on condition. Simple example to turn:

```
if condition:
  foo().bar().baz()
  lots_of_code()
else:
  foo().baz()
  lots_of_code()

def lots_of_code():
  # lots of code
```

into:

```
foo().(if condition: bar()).baz()
# lots of code only once
```

Comment: You can use `getattr` rather than *"dot-syntax-functions"*, so you could do e.g. `getattr(foo() if condition else foo().bar(), 'baz')()`. Or just split it into two lines: `root = foo() if condition else foo().bar(); root.baz()`.

Comment: or `(foo().bar() if condition else foo()).baz()`

Comment: @vaultah I think your idea worked the best. If you post answer I can mark it as a solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it is not possible.

The syntax for attribute reference is

```
attributeref ::=  primary "." identifier
```

Quoting the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#attribute-references),

> An attribute reference is a *primary* followed by a period and a *name*

*name* must be [a regular Python identifier](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#identifiers) and identifiers can't contain special characters like `(`.

However, you can use a simple conditional expression to select *primary*:

```
(foo().bar() if condition else foo()).baz()
```

It's equivalent to

```
if condition:
    primary = foo().bar()
else:
    primary = foo()

primary.baz()
```

Note that in this case we have to use parentheses, because attribute reference has [higher precedence](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence) than conditional expression.

Answer (score 1):

Since `foo()` is called in either case, start by doing so unconditionally. Save that object to `f`, with the intention of calling `f.baz()`. Before that, though, check your condition to see if `f` should really be the result of `foo().bar()`.

```
f = foo()
if condition:
    f = f.bar()
f.baz()
```